# ReferenceError: event is not defined

Tags: jquery, fileupload

Вот этот код выдаёт ReferenceError: event is not defined

```
function fload(files){
    //files = this.files;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'act', 'upload' );
    data.append( 'file', files[0] );

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){ 
            if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){ amsg('Файл загружен!'); get_files(); }
        }
    });
}
```

Вот здесь запускается

```
$('input[type=\"file\"]').bind('change', function(){fload(this.files);});
```

Где здесь ошибка помогите разобраться

Comment: У вас не определен event, вам надо его добавить в аргумент функции `fload(event, this.files)`, и при определении функции `function fload(event, files)`

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin , я так сделал, теперь ругается на строку где запускается $('input[type=\"file\"]').bind('change', function(){fload(event, this.files);});

Comment: @Dmitriy `bind('change', function(event) { fload(event, this.files); });`